Shortest distance between a curve and a line in an interval that they don't intersect
So I got this problem:
What is the shortest distance between $f(x)=-x^3+3x^2+1$ and $g(x)=-9x+45$ on the interval $(0,+\infty)$.

Obviously I can use the distance formula here, but the point on $f(x)$ that satisfy the shortest distance ($x=3$) is also where the tangent line of $f(x)$ is parallel to $g(x)$ and the distance is their common normal. I want to prove this generally for all cases, but what happens if the two graphs don't intersect on the interval $(a,b)$, but intersect right outside the interval? Is this still true? 
Is there any condition for this to be true?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I want to find a general solution for the problem: find the shortest distance between a curve and a line on an interval that they don't intersect. Is "the shortest distance is their common normal" true for all cases?

You need to check the ends of the intervals as well. Use a simple example something like two straight lines. If I use the same interval, $[0\infty)$, then a simple example is $y=0$ and $y=x+1$. They don't have a common normal, so the shortest distance happens at the end of the interval.
Even better, let the interval be $[-1.1,1.2]$ and the functions $y=x^2$ and $y=x^4+1$. The graph of these looks like

The common normal is at $x0$, where the distance is $1$, but you need to check the ends $x=-1.1$ and $x=1.2$. I've specifically used different distances from $0$ for the end of the intervals, just to show that you need to check both. See what would happen if the lower end is $-1.25$, $-1$, or $-0.5$.

So how do I prove that the shortest distance is the common normal, like the example I gave? The two graphs intersect at really far away

See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2882830
